# Why no Spring 'Template Beans' context menu option

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using 2017 Ultimate (trial).  I do Alt+insert and get only 'Constructor', 'toString()' etc options. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you please explain what "Template Beans" are? What entries are you missing?

Comment: I'm unable to do the following:  tinyurl.com/ycxqxnw2

Comment: These apply only to Spring XML configuration files. There are none for code configuration.

Comment: Really? That's rubbish!  Thanks.

Comment: Please feel free to suggest the ones you miss for code setups in our issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA Thanks.